# Thread and Message Queue Architecture. Java and C++ difference

Tags: java, c++

I am learning from Java for Android and some of things I learned about Thread and Message Queue as followed.

1)Main thread has its own message queue and new thread can be formed through Handler in message queue.

2)The new thread when ran, can also have it's own message queue. The communication from new thread to main thread is through same handler.

I have some questions, in C++ inter thread communication wan't done by handler. I think it's done by message queues or pipes.

My questions, how do I relate the Handler concept from Java with message queue or pipe from C++ in terms of communication between Main thread and secondary thread.

Comment: It depends on the operating system. `Handler` is an Android thing more so than a Java thing.

Comment: what's the best way for inter thread communication?

Comment: It really depends on what you're trying to do. It's fairly straightforward to create a message queue concept yourself if you have a specific type of data that you're trying to move across. Basically you can just access the same collection and protect access to it, using condition variables to alert a waiting thread that there's data in the queue. There is also some new stuff in the C++11 thread header that might be helpful. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread

Answer (score 0):

In Java and C++, you can have Handlers, or Message Queues, or pass command objects which is how ExecutorServices work.

Java tends to prefer hiding the details away from you and leaving you to write only the most essential code (even if the language itself it pretty verbose)  C++ tends to prefer exposing the low level constructs.

However, there is no reason you cannot do either in each language.

BTW: I prefer passing command objects `Runnable` and `Callable` to ExecutorServices in Java. i.e. no handlers or message queue or threads to worry about.